# Odd(?) behaviour of a temporary std::ostringstream

Tags: c++

I was messing around with `std::ostringstream` whilst looking at this question: [sprintf in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963242/sprintf-in-c), and noticed the `stringbuilder()` wrapper by Nawaz and thought, well that ought to work with `std::ostringstream`.

So my first attempt was the following:

```
std::cout << (std::ostringstream("select * from foo limit") << max_limit).str() << std::endl;
```

Now this obviously fails to compile (correctly) as the result of the `operator<<` is a `std::ostream` - which doesn't have the member `str()`. So I thought a cast should do the trick, and specifically a cast to a `const` reference (works with a cast to a normal reference too), so second attempt:

```
std::cout << static_cast<std::ostringstream const&>(std::ostringstream("select * from foo limit") << max_limit).str() << std::endl;
```

Now this compiles fine and runs, however the output is, well, not what I was expecting.

> 10lect * from foo limit

Now - here's the question, am I invoking some undefined behaviour somewhere - and if so where? And how is this different to the approach that Nawaz has taken (I guess aside from the result of his operator is the `stringbuilder` itself rather than `std::ostream`).

EDIT: here is the [ideone code](http://www.ideone.com/7gxFo).

EDIT: oops - forgot to specify, `max_limit` is `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move the stream's position to the end of the internal buffer used by `ostringstream`:

```
  std::ostringstream out("select * from foo limit ", std::ios_base::app);
  out << max_limit;
  std::cout << out.str () << std::endl;
```

See the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/ostringstream/) on `ostringstream` constructor.

Comment: Ah, that may be it. It's shocking that the two-argument ctor for `ostringstream` doesn't have `app` as the default.

Comment: BTW, cplusplus.com is notoriously error-ridden. Recommending it is not recommended. :)

Comment: @Tomalak What would you suggest as an online c++ reference instead?

Comment: @Nim - A stringstream initialized with a string is positioned to **read** from the string. If we changed from the current default, we would just get the other set of questions! :-)

Comment: @Nim: As did I. :) @Bo: For an `ostringstream` as opposed to an `istringstream` or bi-directional `stringstream`, this still feels backwards.

Comment: @Bo Persson, it's a `std::ostringstream` - which AFAIK is only ever used for outputting content to a string, so isn't it realistic to assume that append is the default mode of operation?

Comment: @Nim - It sort of is appending, if you just don't provide the first string in the constructor. I believe the decision was made for stringstream, which is both in and out. Where should that start? Read or write as the first operation? And now that you know how it works, you can add an extra parameter to the constructor.

Comment: @Bo, still not convinced, it makes no sense for `ostringstream`, ah well, there's little that can be done about it - we have to live with it...

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks, I didn't expect to find the current draft in that collection; big thanks. Also a big thanks to your very active involvement and knowledge here.

Answer (score 2):

What's `maxLimit`?

Some of the `ostream` `operator<<` overloads are free functions, like:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, T const&);
```

If the stream is a temporary (which in your case it is), it cannot bind to that `ref-to-non-const`, and the overload cannot be chosen.

So you may be using a non-preferred overload by accident; possibly something like the overload for `char const*`. Hard to tell without knowing what `maxLimit` is.

This is a limitation when trying to do this serialisation on a single line, and you can't get around it.

You're also attempting to stream `std::cout` to `std::cout`, which is obviously not what you intended to do.

**Update** Vijay figured it out.

```
std::cout << static_cast<std::ostringstream const&>(
   std::ostringstream("select * from foo limit", std::ios_base::app) << max_limit
).str() << std::endl
```

The above is still definitely worth bearing in mind, though.

Comment: Updated the question. Actually - that would make sense.

Comment: I don't get your last point, I just wanted to print out the string in the temporary.

Comment: @Nim: `std::cout << (stuff) << std::cout`?

Comment: Fixed the typo, on ideone where I was testing, it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply use `flush` as:

```
static_cast<std::ostringstream const&>(std::ostringstream().flush() << "select * from foo limit " << max_limit).str() << std::endl;
```

But then the code is not same. Its using default constructor.

As a sidenote :  isn't `dynamic_cast` more appropriate here?

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/06xNS

Comment: why `dynamic_cast`? I could understand if `std::ostringstream` derived from multiple bases, it doesn't just `std::ostream`, so surely the `static_cast` is sufficient?

Comment: @Nim: Its downcasting, so I think `dynamic_cast` is more appropriate, though `static_cast` would work fine since you're sure that *dynamic* type is `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: Generally you should avoid casts. There is no need for any casts here, just take out the `ostringstream` from the `std::cout <<` call.

Comment: @Vijay: That would produce the same result, I agree; I know that @Nim knows that as well. But that isn't what Nim was trying to do; he wanted to do that just in one line (if I understood his intention correctly).