# dynamic construction of strings in c++ - what is a more c++-ish way to do this?

Tags: c++, c

I want to build a string label with a changing suffix. This is to take place within a for-loop. (The suffix being the value that is looped through). This is how I'd do it in C - is there a more c++-ish way to do this?

```
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
    char label[256];

    sprintf(label, "Label_no_%d", i);

    // convert label to a c plus plus string

    // Do stuff with the string here
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use stringstreams:

```
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
    std::ostringstream label;

    label << "Label_no_" << i;

    // use label.str() to get the string it built
}
```

These let you use `operator<<`, exactly like you would for `std::cout` or a file, but writing to an in memory string instead.

Or alternatively you can use [Boost.Format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7584035/168175), which behaves more like `sprintf` with a C++ interface.

Comment: Thank you awoodland, JohnB, rve, NFRCR, and John Purdy for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

Use stringstream :-

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << "Label_no" << i; 

    std::string label = ss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `boost::lexical_cast`

```
std::string label = "Label_no_" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's std::to_string() for converting a numeric value to a string. (C++11)

Answer (score 1):

The code says it all. Use `ostringstream` from the `<sstream>` header—it’s an `ostream` backed by a `string` buffer. It’s not as efficient as `sprintf()` because of the dynamic allocation, but that won’t matter unless this is in a hot part of the program, and using `stringstream` is worth it for the safety.

```
#include <sstream>

for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {

    std::ostringstream label;
    label << "Label_no_" << i;

    use(label.str());

}
```

Comment: @rve: Typo. Nobody’s perfect.