# How to extract formatted text in C++?

Tags: c++, text, formatted

This might have appeared before, but I couldn't understand how to extract formatted data. Below is my code to extract all text between string "[87]" and "[90]" in a text file.

Apparently, the position of [87] and [90] is the same as indicated in the output.

```
void ExtractWebContent::filterContent(){
    string str, str1;
    string positionOfCurrency1 = "[87]";
    string positionOfCurrency2 = "[90]";
    size_t positionOfText1, positionOfText2;
    ifstream reading;
    reading.open("file_Currency.txt");
    while (!reading.eof()){ 
        getline (reading, str);

        positionOfText1 = str.find(positionOfCurrency1);
        positionOfText2 = str.find(positionOfCurrency2);
        cout << "positionOfCurrency1 " << positionOfText1 << endl;
        cout << "positionOfCurrency2 " << positionOfText2 << endl;

        //str1= str.substr (positionOfText);
        cout << "String" << str1 << endl;
    }

    reading.close();
```

An Update on the currency file:

[79]More »Brent slips to $102 on worries about euro zone economy

Market Data

```
 * Currencies
```

CAPTION: Currencies

```
      Name      Price    Change % Chg
   [80]USD/SGD
              1.2606     -0.00  -0.13%

                                       USD/SGD [81]USDSGD=X
   [82]EUR/SGD
              1.5242     0.00   +0.11%

                                       EUR/SGD [83]EURSGD=X
```

Comment: You might like [my older answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7584035/168175) which used Boost Format for the output

Comment: I wrote a very general answer that should send you in the right direction. If you can add the actual file format I can be more specific.

Comment: I have updated the text file which content is to be extracted. It seems getline is a possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

That really depends on what 'extracting data means'. In simple cases you can just read the [file into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring) and then use [string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) member functions (especially `find` and `substr`) to extract the segment you are interested in. If you are interested in data per line [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is the way to go for line extraction. Apply `find` and `substr` as before to get the segment.

Sometimes a simple `find` wont get you far and you will need a [regular expression](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) to do easily get to the parts you are interested in.

Often simple parsers evolve and soon outgrow even `regular expressions`. This often signals time for the very large hammer of C++ parsing [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Boost.Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/tokenizer/) can be helpful for parsing out a string, but it gets a little trickier if those delimiters have to be bracketed numbers like you have them.  With the delimieters as described, a regex is probably adequate.

Answer (score 0):

All that does is concatenate the output of reading and the strings "[1]" and "[2]". I'm guessing this code resulted from a rather literal extrapolation of similar code using `scanf`. `scanf` (as well as the rest of C) still works in C++, so if that works for you I would use it.

That said, there are various levels of sophistication at which you can do this. Using regexes is one of the most powerful/flexible ways, but it might be overkill. The quickest way in my opinion is just to do something like:

- Find index of substring "[1]", `i1`
- Find index of substring "[2]", `i2`
- get substring between `i1+3` and `i2`.

In code, supposing `std::string line` has the text:

```
size_t i1 = line.find("[1]");
size_t i2 = line.find("[2]");
std::string out(line.substr(i1+3, i2));
```

Warning: no error checking.

Comment: Right, I have done it as shown above. But the returning position of 2 size_t is the same! How can we resolve this? Thanks!